# Can "thick preferences" be represented by a utility function?

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

From microeconomics,
$u$ is strictly quasi-concave if for all $x\ne y\in\mathbb{R}^2_+$ and $t \in (0,1)$, if $u(x)\ge u(y)$, then $u(tx + (1-t)y)>u(y)$.
You may also check the figure below.

[image]

**Here preferences are convex and utility is quasi-concave.
I wonder if we can represent or not the thick preferences by a utility function?
Thanks.**

Comment: What does “thick preferences” mean?

Comment: http://www.econ.ucla.edu/sboard/teaching/econ11_09/econ11_09_lecture2.pdf   you may check the page 8.

Comment: Thanks. I actually find this interesting. +1

Comment: I find confusing much more than interesting though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are utility functions with thick indifference curves, e.g., take any utility function $u(x,y)$ and run it through the integer part function so $\lfloor u(x,y) \rfloor$. Resulting preference will have thick indifference curves.

As to whether

> we can represent or not the thick preferences

depends on your exact definition of thick preferences. It is not difficult to alter the lexicographic preference so that on a small range it becomes "thick". E.g., alter the order by making all bundles where $x<1$ equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and time.